# Failed to parse asynchronously multiple XML documents using aalto

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax, woodstox

I'm trying to parse XML message coming out a tcp socket using **Aalto-xml**

https://github.com/FasterXML/aalto-xml

This is the xml I'm trying to parse:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<employee>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Alba</name>
    <salary>100</salary>
</employee>
```

The first xml message is parsed successfully, but on the 2nd one it throws an exception.
Here is my parse method

In my class I define a class member:

```
private AsyncXMLStreamReader<AsyncByteArrayFeeder> parser = new InputFactoryImpl().createAsyncForByteArray();
```

Parse Method:

```
try {
        parser.getInputFeeder().feedInput(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

        int type = 0;

        //keep looping till event is complete
        while(!parser.getInputFeeder().needMoreInput()) {
                type = parser.next();
            //handle parser event and extract parsed data
            switch (type) {
                case XMLEvent.START_DOCUMENT:
                    System.out.println("start document");
                    break;

                case XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT: {
                     System.out.println("start element: " + parser.getName());
                } break;

                case XMLEvent.END_ELEMENT: {
                    System.out.println("end element: " + parser.getName());
                    } break;

                case XMLEvent.END_DOCUMENT: {
                    System.out.println("end document");
                }break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        if(type == AsyncXMLStreamReader.EVENT_INCOMPLETE) {
                System.out.println(results);
        }

    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
com.fasterxml.aalto.WFCException: Illegal processing instruction target: 'xml' (case insensitive) is reserved by the xml specification
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,112]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that same content is being fed multiple times or something, so that XML declaration gets passed more than once. This because of offset mentioned in the exception (column `122`).

Comment: Yeah, it might be the case.

Comment: Question: for every xml - Do I need to re-initialize: xmlInputFactory.createAsyncForByteArray() ??

Comment: It seems that when streaming xml directly from the socket, I need to create new Async ByteArray for every new message, otherwise it throws exceptions like the buffer is not cleaned and it fails when trying to parse the next xml element type.

Comment: it seems I cannot reuse the async-buffer after the first message was processed. I get an xml buffer from socket, but when I feed it and then try to parse it - it also throws an exception!

Comment: @Shvalb this should not be the case, reuse is perfectly fine. But make sure you are giving only real content that buffer does contain: reads could be for only part of the buffer?

Comment: The problem is that when I read the last tag I need to invoke feeder.endOfInput(); otherwise it won't progress to XMLEvent.END_DOCUMENT (8) and in this case if I feed it with new content it throws exception. so if I do invoke it then I cannot feed it with new content!

Comment: @Shvalb you should only ever call `endOfInput`, when -- as the name implies -- there is absolutely no more content to parse. To know when you need to feed more input you should only check for `EVENT_INCOMPLETE`: you will only get that when there isn't enough input to decode any more tokens. A simple example is found from http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/03/entry_451.html although Aalto project tests also show usage.

Also note that if you really have all the content in buffer already, there's no point to use non-blocking: code would never block anyway.

Comment: So, the problem is that when I receive EVENT_INCOMPLETE and I feed new Xml data it throws exception. What about END_DOCUMENT - When should I expect to get this event?

Comment: @Shvalb you will only receive `END_DOCUMENT` after indicating end of the document -- otherwise it would still be possible there was more content, possibly outside root element (comments, processing instructions). What you describe (getting `EVENT_INCOMPLETE`, feeding data, getting exception) sounds like a bug, so filing a bug report with reproduction (unit test) would make sense. Or it may be problem with code: but determining this requires reproduction with code and data.

Comment: I'll open an issue with reproduction. Thank you.